# Как расшифровать текст(найти ключ шифрования) имея список шифруемых слов и соответствующих им зашифрованных значений?

Tags: python, массивы, шифрование

Подскажите пожалуйста как быстрее и проще решить следующую задачу:
Имеется два списка. Список1 - шифруемые слова(только латиница, разная длина слов). Список2 - зашифрованные слова из Списка1(только 8 цифр). Как найти ключ шифрования?
Например:

after   87405074

salads  49499553

pasting 44832253

cuts    35055669

Comment: по-моему, не зная алгоритм шифрования / хеширования, придется перебирать все возможные алгоритмы шифрования со всеми возможными ключами ;)

Comment: В общем случае **никак**.